# Scrapy - How to scrape a weblink within a weblink using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape:

https://webmd.com/oral-health/oral-lichen-planus#1 from webmd website in the following web page code:

```
<li class="global-nav-sign-in global-nav-hide-mobile" data-metrics-module="">
            <a href="https://member.webmd.com/signin?appid=1&amp;returl=https://www.webmd.com/oral-health/oral-lichen-planus#1" data-metrics-link="reg-login">Sign In</a>
        </li>
```

I use the following scrapy code to achieve this:

```
import scrapy
import re
import string
import pandas as pd

class HealthItem(scrapy.Item):
    link = scrapy.Field()


def urls_getter():
    fname = "/home/phil/fd/webmd/health.csv"
    pds = pd.read_csv(fname)
    pds_link = pds['link']
    pds_link = pds_link.drop_duplicates(keep = "first", inplace = False)
    pds_link = pds_link.tolist()
    return pds_link


class SymptommdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "symptommd"
    allowed_domains = ["webmd.com"]
    start_urls = urls_getter()
    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "global-nav-sign-in")]/a[contains(@href, "https:")]')
        for title in titles:
            item = HealthItem()
            item['link'] =  title.xpath('@href').extract()
            yield item
```

However, this code gets only the front portion of the a href.  Namely, https://member.webmd.com/signin.  How do I get only the second web link?

Comment: This is exactly how `@href` appears in page source. What is your desired output?

Comment: The outcome is https://member.webmd.com/signin but I need https://webmd.com/oral-health/oral-lichen-planus#1.  Here is the sample url: https://www.webmd.com/oral-health/oral-lichen-planus#1

Comment: Looks like this part of URL is added with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the URL is built with Javascript. If you look at the raw HTML, it looks like this:

[image: Raw HTML]

Does it really matter anyway? This URL https://member.webmd.com/signin points you to a valid page.

If this matters, then you need some extra logic to extract the info from the Javascript, or you can hardcode the full URL in your code.